# Custom Metal Kernel function not found in the default app bundle

Tags: swift, xcode, metal, core-image

I am in the process of writing a command-line MacOS application to play with custom Metal kernels for CoreImage filtering. I have a simple kernel that basically does nothing - returns the same pixel information to the output:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

using namespace metal;

extern "C" {
    namespace coreimage {
        float4 foobar(sample_t s, float opacity) {
            return float4(s.rgba);
        }
    }
}
```

I than initialise CIColorKernel like so:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "metallib")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
try kernel = CIColorKernel(functionName: "foobar", fromMetalLibraryData: data)!
```

This works just fine when testing from within the Xcode itself. However, when I build my command-line application for running and actually run it from the terminal I am getting the following error:

```
Error Domain=CIKernel Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={CINonLocalizedDescriptionKey=Function does not exist in library data. }
```

This implies that my custom function `foobar` cannot be found in the main (default) metallib. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you compile your Metal code with the `-fcikernel` compiler and `-cikernel` linker flag in your release build?

Comment: Hello, Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

As Frank Schlegel correctly pointed out in the comments, you need a special compiler option and a linker flag.

Here is what the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel/2880194-init) says:

> To use MSL as the shader language for a CIKernel, you must specify some options in Xcode under the Build Settings tab of your project's target. The first option you need to specify is an `-fcikernel` flag in the *Other Metal Compiler Flags* option. The second is to add a user-defined setting with a key called `MTLLINKER_FLAGS` with a value of `-cikernel`:

[image]